# Running Bluestacks on AWS or Google cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, bluestacks

Is there any way to run Bluestacks on virtualized instances in the cloud.

I tried both AWS, GCE, both failed.

AWS fails with the message "Failed due to enabled Hyper-V", even It's disabled in the settings.

And GCE just cannot start bluestacks, it simply loads and finally says "couldn't start Bluestacks"

What's interesting that these guys managed to do it.. https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Cognosys-Inc-1-Click-Ready-Secured-BlueStacks-App-/B01N0E0YYZ

But how? Cannot use their image as it's old.

Comment: You could look at this [documentation](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360014581811-System-requirements-for-BlueStacks-4), that explains about system requirements for Bluestack. To run Bluestack you need Graphic card and to know more about GPUs available in the GCE, refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/). However, you can use the pricing [calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#id=29ed1145-3ad3-4197-907a-19cae6da3691) to estimate the monthly cost.

Answer (score 1):

Bluestack doesn't work for me too. I saw Cognosys but they are running on Windows Server 2012 which is really old.

Try Memu Play 2GB Ram Minimum (Try the 4GB VPS)
Windows Server 2019 Base
DirectX

It works for me