# Is there a way to enable VT-X on Windows Server 2019 running through Google Cloud Platform

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, windows-server-2019

I am attempting to install the android emulator MEMU, onto a Windows Server 2019 instance running on Google Cloud Platform. Whenever I try to launch the emulator, the launcher is stopped at 59%. I did some research and found that I need to have Intel's virtualization technology enabled. However,  it looks like the only way to enable the VT-X is to go into the BIOS and do it. Since I'm connected to the machine through remote desktop, that's not possible. From this post: [Running Bluestacks on AWS or Google cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034039/running-bluestacks-on-aws-or-google-cloud), the person who answered the question seemed to be able to use MEMU. Additionally, I tried enabling Hyper-V, which allowed the emulator to reach 99%. Any help figuring out how to run MEMU on google cloud platform is appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances specifically `Windows VMs do not support nested virtualization;`

Comment: No, I did not. Is there any explanation for MEMU working for the person in the linked post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [system requirements of MEmu](https://www.memuplay.com/blog/system-requirements.html):

> - x86/x86_64 Processor (Intel or AMD CPU)
> - WinXP SP3 / Win7 / Win8 / Win8.1 / Win10
> - Windows DirectX 11 / Graphic driver with OpenGL 2.0
> - **Hardware Virtualization Technology (Intel VT-x/AMD-V)** shall be enabled in BIOS
> - Minimum 2GB of system memory
> - Minimum 2GB of hard disk free space

and

> It’s not recommended to run MEmu App Player in another virtual machine
>   software.

As it was mentioned by *@Morrison Chang*, **you're not able to use nested virtualization with Windows VMs**, more details you can find in the documentation [Enabling Nested Virtualization for VM Instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances):

> **Nested virtualization adds support for [Intel VT-x](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-virtualization-developer-community) processor virtualization instructions to Compute Engine VMs.** Using nested
>   virtualization, you start a VM instance as normal on Compute Engine
>   and then install a KVM-compatible hypervisor on the VM instance so you
>   can run another VM instance on top of that hypervisor. **You can use
>   nested virtualization on any Linux VM instance** running on a Haswell
>   or newer platform. **For other constraints, see the sub-section,
>   [restrictions for nested virtualization](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances#restrictions)**.

and

> **[Restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances#restrictions)**
>
> **Windows VMs do not support nested virtualization**; that is, host VMs
>   must run a Linux OS. However, nested VMs can run certain Windows OSes
>   (described below).

**To solve your issue** you can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) at [Google Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) under [this component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187208&template=1162952) and ask for VT-x support for Windows VMs.

Also, as a possible workaround, you can check [Google Cloud Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/?_ga=2.191597930.1785756846.1585552189-1698584973.1584367323) and search for available android emulators, but they could be non-free.

**UPDATE**

Topics like [Running Bluestacks on AWS or Google cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034039/running-bluestacks-on-aws-or-google-cloud) at Stack Overflow or other unofficial resources shouldn't be treated as proof of undocumented features, functions or workarounds. As I can see, *@Artem Ibragimov* tried AWS and GCE and it was fruitless, also *@CodeGuru* didn't provide any information on which cloud platform he succeeded:

> Bluestack doesn't work for me too. I saw Cognosys but they are running
>   on Windows Server 2012 which is really old.
>
> Try Memu Play 2GB Ram Minimum (Try the 4GB VPS) Windows Server 2019
>   Base DirectX
>
> It works for me